# servlet mysql not in statements

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets

I'm creating a servlet that executes a sql query, the basic version of it works however when I add the NOT IN statement it returns a null pointer exception. I'd rather it not do that but instead display a message that says that they can't enroll in a subject.

here are the relevant tables

```
user - id, name, password

subject - id, name, user_id

lab - id, time, room, capacity, subject_id

user_lab - id, user_id, lab_id
```

what I'm trying to write is a statement that says if a user isn't already enrolled in a lab please print the `subject.name, lab.time, lab.room`

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        //Set data you want to send back to the request (will be forwarded to the page)
        //Can set string, int, list, array etc.

     String id = request.getParameter("id"); 
     System.out.println("beej");
     int user_id = 0; 

     if(id != null && (!id.equals("")) ) { 
     user_id= Integer.parseInt(id); 
     } 

     String sql = "SELECT l.id,s.name,l.day,l.time,l.room" +
              " FROM subject s, lab l " +
                " WHERE" +
                " s.id = l.subject_id"+
                            " AND l.id "+"NOT IN"+
                "SELECT l.id"+
                " FROM lab ll, user_lab ul" +
                "WHERE"+"l.id ="+"ul.lab_id" + "AND ul.user_id="+(Integer)session.getAttribute("id");


      try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");

        System.out.println(session.getAttribute("id"));

          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          System.out.println(res);
          ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
          if (res.next()){
              do{
                   list1.add(res.getString(1));
                   list2.add(res.getString(2)+" "+res.getString(3)+" "+res.getString(4)+" "+res.getString(5));


              }while(res.next());

          String[] arr1 = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
          String[] arr2 = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
          System.out.println(list2);
          request.setAttribute("res1", arr1);
          request.setAttribute("res2", arr2);
          request.setAttribute("user_id", user_id);

          }



      }catch (SQLException e) {
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        } 


        //Decides what page to send the request data to
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Student_enrol.jsp");
        //Forward to the page and pass the request and response information
        view.forward(request, response); 




org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:534)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    Student_enrol.sendBack(Student_enrol.java:104)
    Student_enrol.doGet(Student_enrol.java:40)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.Student_005fenrol_jsp._jspService(Student_005fenrol_jsp.java:95)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    Student_enrol.sendBack(Student_enrol.java:104)
    Student_enrol.doGet(Student_enrol.java:40)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

add a space between `NOT IN` and `SELECT`

```
" s.id = l.subject_id"+
" AND l.id "+"NOT IN  " +     // <== here
"SELECT l.id"+
```

you subquery should look like this

```
SELECT..
FROM...
WHERE l.id NOT IN
(
   SELECT..
   FROM...
)
```

Comment: wrap the `SELECT` in a subquery.

Comment: And `()` around the sub-query

Comment: @user1393064 check the value of this `(Integer)session.getAttribute("id")`

Comment: its printing out the correct value. when printing it before the sql statement

Answer (score 0):

You also need some spaces around "WHERE" and before "AND"

```
"WHERE"+"l.id ="+"ul.lab_id" + "AND ul.user_id="+(Integer)session.getAttribute("id");
```

should be

```
" WHERE "+"l.id ="+"ul.lab_id" + " AND ul.user_id="+(Integer)session.getAttribute("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes to yout code :

```
  if (res.next()){
          do{
               list1.add(res.getString(1));
               list2.add(res.getString(2)+" "+res.getString(3)+" "+res.getString(4)+" "+res.getString(5));


          }while(res.next());
      String[] arr1 = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
      String[] arr2 = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
      System.out.println(list2);
      request.setAttribute("res1", arr1);
      request.setAttribute("res2", arr2);
```

to:

```
  String[] arr1 = null;
  String[] arr2 = null;
  while(res.next()){
       list1.add(res.getString(1));
       list2.add(res.getString(2)+" "+res.getString(3)+" "+res.getString(4)+" "+res.getString(5));
      arr1 = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
      arr2 = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
          }
  request.setAttribute("res1", arr1);
  request.setAttribute("res2", arr2);
```

This is because when you try to print an empty list2 or access list1 and list2 it will throw error. To avoid that use them only when rows are existing.

And also add space between words in query as mentioned by John Woo :)